# PHP Files being cached by unknown entity

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, cache

I'm hitting a weird cache issue on my server, the project I am working on doesn't have any caching enabled at this time, but the server it self has APC installed (which was set to cache everything by default, this has been disabled now).

The problem is, my old code is running still, and I don't know how to get the amended code to trigger.

I have tried deleting the file entirely, this makes my project error with "missing file" as it should, but once I upload my file (new version), it starts serving up the old version of the file again.

I've uploaded a uniquely labeled file with `apc_clear_cache();` and `apc_clear_cache( 'opcode' );` but this didn't appear to help.

I have also commented out APC from loading with PHP, but it still served old files, so I am wondering if there's something underlying that is causing this aggressive caching.

Apache2, PHP, APC etc is all loaded up using Aptitude on Debian Wheezy

PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u3 (running under mod_php)
Apache 2.2.22

Between each config change and disabling APC I did a complete apache restart.

I've checked the apache2 modules list, no cache modules are loaded up, there are also no services such as varnish etc running.

**Update**

Did some additional testing, added some html output before the `<?php` tag which is output, so content outside the php tags aren't being cached it seems.

The file that isn't updating is being included with `include_once()` and disabling APC didn't appear to have any kind of impact on the file being served incorrectly.

The problem is with tryign to use HTML2PDF to generate a .pdf file after form submission

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ERROR File : /lib/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php Line : 1319, Impossible to load the image 'logo.png' thrown in /lib/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php on line 1319`

The new version of the file uses `logo.jpg`

Comment: How is the file in question being run?  Via `{include,require}{,_once}()`?  If so, how is the file you are using to test being run?  For example, could this be an issue of browser cache?

Comment: Assuming it's not being reached directly, try adding some disk logging (or `syslog()`) to both the calling page and the file in question.

Comment: The file in question is being added using `include_once()`. It isn't a browser cache because the included file is a php script trying to include the image and my error log is picking spitting out that the image file isn't found and referencing the old image filename which is wrong (it has been changed in the new version of the file that I can't load)

Comment: It sounds like a situation where you are editing, for example, the copy of the file in `/var/www2/html`, whereas the DocRoot is set to `/var/www/html`.  Try something like `updatedb && locate somefile.php` to see where else it might be finding the file in question.

Comment: Unfortunately not the case, since I can see changes I make outside the PHP tags it seems to be some interpreter holding on to the PHP code very tightly, and it's happening over multiple projects not just this one site.

Comment: Consider disabling any other accelerators or code-encryption providers, such as Zend or Ioncube.  Also, as a debugging step, add an `echo` above the code that is erroring out, just in case you're not quite running the code you think you are.

Comment: Same problem here also without APC really weird behaviour :(

Answer (score 0):

In APC, this most commonly would happen as a result of `apc.stat` being turned off, or stat'ing ctime instead of mtime or vice versa, depending on your SCCS.  You may wish to verify that APC is truly disabled via something like `phpinfo()`.

Comment: I've checked that it's stat'ing for mtime, and `apc.stat` is enabled.
After disabling APC I checked with phpinfo and it is indeed not active any more but I am still seeing a cached copy of the file being ran.